# Does a statement such as this require quotation marks?

Tags: punctuation

If a person said something like "Who threw that?" and after getting no reply, he then said "I said who threw that?"  How would one punctuate the second sentence?  Would it be:

I said, "Who threw that"!

or

I said "Who threw that"!

or

I said who threw that!

Answer (score 2):

The first form is the orthographically correct one. The quotes are required, and the comma is customary.

The quotes are required because the clause being reported is verbatim speech; it is not a subclause.

Compare:

> I said (to him), "Who threw that?"
>
> I asked (him) who threw that.
>
> He said (that) he did.
>
> He said, "I did."

Comment: But what if the writer is 3rd person? _"I said, 'Who threw that', he said"_ ? ;)

Comment: @mplungjan I'm afraid you have the quotes in the wrong places. Either ["I said, 'Who threw that?'", he said.] or [I said, "'Who threw that?', he said"].

Comment: Sorry, I edited on my phone and moved the last quote by mistake. I meant to write _"I said, 'Who threw that'", he said_